# How to use ContentResolver class instead of MediaStore.Images.Media.query method that is was deprecated in API level 29?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I'm using the [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media#query(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method that is inside [MediaStore.Images.Media](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media) class but it's was deprecated in API level 29.

It's telling me to use [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver) class instead, But I don't know what is the correct way to use it.

Could you leave an example of how to use [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver) class to reach the same result of the code below?

```
String id = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
String bucketId = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q ? MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID : "bucket_id";
String bucketDisplayName = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q ? MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME : "bucket_display_name";
String data = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q ? MediaStore.Images.Media._ID : MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;

Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Media.query(
        requireContext().getContentResolver(),
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{id, bucketId, bucketDisplayName, data},
        MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE + " <= " + (1000 * 1000 * MainActivity.MAXIMUM_OF_IMAGE_SIZE),
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q ? MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " desc" : "datetaken desc");
```

Comment: Read stackoverflow pages tagged `mediastore`.